# Python, regular expression, strings inside brackets [ ]

Tags: python, regex, string, bioinformatics

In lines like:
(bla - means not important)

```
> blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Geobacter sp. M21]
> blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Acetobacter pasteurianus IFO 3283-07]
> blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Gardnerella vaginalis ATCC 14019]
> blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1]
```

I tried to get all information inside brackets [ ] 
as :

```
Geobacter sp. M21
Acetobacter pasteurianus IFO 3283-07
Gardnerella vaginalis ATCC 14019
Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1
```

my code here, of course it doesn't work - in [ ] would be  sometimes 3, sometimes 4 "alfanumeric words", there are also characters like " . " or " - ":

```
import re
#code...
pattern = r'[ \w+ \w+ \w+ ]'
for i in lines_:
    m = re.search ( pattern, str(i) )
    print m.group()
```

So is this possible to get those information using regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I make it that way:

```
for i in list_:
    dop = re.search("\[(.+)\]$", str(i))
    if dop:
        species=dop.group(0)
```

explanation:

```
\[      # [
(       # start of a capture group
.+      # One or more characters because some of them had brackets inside []
        # like > bla|bla [Salmonella enterica subsp. 4,[5],12:i:- str. 08-1736]
)       # The close of the capture group
\]      # ]
$       # matching from the end of line
```

thank you all for help

Answer (score 7):

No need of regex here:

```
>>> s = '''> blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Geobacter sp. M21]
... > blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Acetobacter pasteurianus IFO 3283-07]
... > blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Gardnerella vaginalis ATCC 14019]
... > blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1]'''
>>> for x in s.splitlines():
...     print x.rsplit('[')[-1].rstrip(']')
...     
Geobacter sp. M21
Acetobacter pasteurianus IFO 3283-07
Gardnerella vaginalis ATCC 14019
Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `lines_` to [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and use a Regex pattern such as this:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

Below is a breakdown of what it is matching:

```
\[      # [
(       # The start of a capture group
[^\]]+  # One or more characters that are not ]
)       # The close of the capture group
\]      # ]
```

And here is a demonstration:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> lines_ = """
... > blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Geobacter sp. M21]
... > blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Acetobacter pasteurianus IFO 3283-07]
... > blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Gardnerella vaginalis ATCC 14019]
... > blabla|blabla|bla|blabla| blabla [Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1]
... """
>>> findall("\[([^\]]+)\]", lines_)
['Geobacter sp. M21', 'Acetobacter pasteurianus IFO 3283-07', 'Gardnerella vaginalis ATCC 14019', 'Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1']
>>>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `$`.